# Change Background in nav_header_main

Tags: java, android

I try to change the Background of my Navigation Drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing" android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" android:id="@+id/textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a drawable picture but when i put it into android:background = "@drawable/test" it doesnt work. Can somebody help me to change the Background?

I want to change this color into a picture

[i want this color changed :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3LFr.png)

Greetings 
JK

Comment: Post logcat outpot for more help.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
You have a problem with your files. Make sure that you are passing the correct file to your background

Comment: in drawable/side_nav_bar is the background it looks like this:

Comment: <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#81C784"
        android:centerColor="#4CAF50"
        android:endColor="#2E7D32"
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="135"/>
</shape>

Comment: but i cant change it i dont know why

Comment: no i mean the android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" sets up a theme for the layout. It probably sets a background to your layout , so just remove that line

Comment: @user5762515 can you post a screenshot?

Comment: i just want to change android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar" when i start the projekt i have a greenbackground in my navigation drawer but i want a picture there i cant explain why its not working

Comment: yeah no problem :) how do i add a screenshot?

Comment: @user5762515 try this.. delete the xml file at drawble/side_nav_bar and put there the picture that you want to display. Rename the picture to side_nav_bar. It should work

Comment: @user5762515 if you want to add a screenshot, just upload it to imgur and send the link

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\jkamy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: i get this problem when i do this

Comment: @user5762515 what files do you have in your drawable folder? and also did you put your picture in your drawable folder?

Comment: i deleted the side_nave_bar.xml file and put the picture into the drawable file and renamed it into side_nave_bar

Comment: @user5762515 so your app is not running now?

Comment: No it doesnt work i dont understand why when i look at the preview in the xml file everything is fine but when i start it it doesnt work anymore

Comment: can you post the full Logcat error in your post so i can check it

Comment: can you maybe try to set up a new android studio project and use the navigation drawer activity and there you try to change the picture i cant do it i dont know why :(

Comment: @user5762515 i cant do that but you can post all your code in this question so i can check them all

Comment: I found a way to do it :)